# Multithreaded airport

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I am new to programming, need your help. Every N seconds need to output how many aircraft in queue.

Algorithm, which i can't translate code:

1. Create main thread by the plane.
2. Inside the plane start warmUp.
3. After warmUp ended, plane say aiport, i'm warmed up, i'm waiting for the signal that can take off.
4. Airport add plane in queue.
5. Airport looks - there are planes in queue, if yes and there are free band, take band and give away command take off.
6. In plane start func takeOff. He take off and return band is back.
7. Airport get band and understand, that she is free.

My class Airport and class Band:

```
   public class Airport {
    private final BlockingQueue<Band> bands;

    Airport(int bandCount) {
        this.bands = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(bandCount, true);

        for (int i = 0; i < bandCount; i++) {
            bands.add(new Band("Band " + i));
        }
    }

    public void registerPlaneForTakeoff(Plane plane) {

    }

    @NotNull
    public Band waitForAvailableBand() throws InterruptedException {
        Band result = bands.take();
        System.out.println("Band " + result.name + " reserved ");
        return result;
    }

    public void releaseBand(@NotNull Band band) {
        bands.add(band);
    }

    static class Band  {
        public final String name;
        Band(String name) {this.name = name;}
    }
}
```

Class Cargo

```
public class Cargo extends Plane {
    Cargo(String name, Airport airport, int delay) {
        super(name, airport, delay);
    }
}
```

Class Passenger

```
public class Passenger extends Plane {
    Passenger(String name, Airport airport, int delay) {
        super(name, airport, delay);
    }
}
```

Class Plane

```
public abstract class Plane extends Thread {
    public final String name;
    private final Airport airport;
    private final int delay;

    Plane(String name, Airport airport, int delay) {
        this.name = name;
        this.airport = airport;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public int getDelay() {
        return delay;
    }

    public static int rnd(int min, int max) {
        max -=min;
        return (int) (Math.random() * ++ max) + min;
    }

    public void takeOff() {

    }

    public void warmUp() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int time = 1000;
        int time2 = 10000;
        int timeEver = rnd(time,time2);
        Airport.Band band;
        try {
            System.out.println("Warming up start: " + name);
            Thread.sleep(timeEver);
            System.out.println("Warming up finish: " + name + " " + timeEver);
            System.out.println("Reserve band for: " + name);
            band = airport.waitForAvailableBand();
            try {
                System.out.println("Take off: " + name + " from band " + band.name);
                Thread.sleep(getDelay());
                System.out.println("Took off: " + name);

            } finally {
                airport.releaseBand(band);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}

        }
    }
```

Class Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Airport airport = new Airport(3);

        ArrayList<Plane> planes = new ArrayList<>();

        planes.add(new Passenger("1", airport, 5000));
        planes.add(new Cargo("2", airport, 10000));
        planes.add(new Passenger("3", airport, 5000));
        planes.add(new Passenger("4", airport, 5000));
        planes.add(new Cargo("5", airport, 10000));

        planes.forEach(Thread::start);
        planes.forEach(plane -> {
            try {
               plane.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to define what a « band » is for us aeronautical novices. And you need to ask a specific question. If you want a general review of your code, use sister site, Code Review Stack Exchange. This site here is for solving narrowly-focused programming problem.

Comment: @BasilBourque band it is runway, sorry for the inaссuracy.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is how to output the amount of planes in your queue every few seconds? Simply run another thread that does nothing other than updating your display.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("Planes in queue: ");
        System.out.println(queue.size());

        try (
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally blank
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Thanks) I think, my main question "Airport looks - there are planes in queue, if yes and there are free band, take band and give away command take off". He is difficult for me)